# the 13th column can't display in kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, multiple-columns, display

it is more than 13 columns in my kendo grid, but I find that the 13th column content is always hidden. like this,
[13th column content is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WABjG.png)

the code is here, just a demo

```
      columns: [
            {
                field: "priority",
                title: 'col13',
                headerAttributes: {style: "text-align: center;font-weight: bolder"},
                attributes: {style: "text-align: center;"}
            },
            {
                field: "priority",
                title: 'col14',
                headerAttributes: {style: "text-align: center;font-weight: bolder"},
                attributes: {style: "text-align: center;"}
            }
        ]
```

Comment: If you inspect the page the value is there?

Comment: yes,the value exists, but can not display

Comment: If you don't get results you should have errors on your browser. does not seem to be a format problem but you can also check the css. Can you please provide some more code and css?